# Аналог .length в PHP?

Tags: php

Привет. Какой есть аналог `.length` в PHP? Хочу выполнять какое-то действие с условием, что массив не пустой. В JavaScript это так:

```
if(array.length !== 0) {
}
```

А в PHP как?

Comment: вот открыл бы документацию на странице **Массивы → Функции для работы с массивами** и посмотрел бы список функций. или лень?  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский значит в PHP будет `if(count($array) !== 0)`?

Comment: В зависимости от целей... можно и просто `if ($arr) { ...` для пустого он будет как раз false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для подсчёта количества элементов в массиве PHP можно использовать функцию [count](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php).

```
if (count($array) != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Впрочем, для случая выше можно применить функцию [empty](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php).

```
if (!empty($array)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: главное, чтоб где-то выше в коде не оказалось, что в `$array` попадает результат некой функции, которая может вернуть массив или `false`. а то с `count` будет конфуз

Comment: А циклы foreach есть в PHP?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ох уж эта динамическая типизация.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, циклы, разумеется, имеются - `foreach ($array as $key => $value) { ... }`, https://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3):

Есть поверье, что достаточно написать

```
if ($array) { 

}
```

чтобы проверить пуст ли массив или нет. Также это спасет, если в `$array` попадает результат некой функции, которая может вернуть массив или `false`. Такое бывает например у классов-драйверов БД.

Остальные телодвижения с `if (count($array) != 0)` и `if (!empty($array)) {`  для проверки массива на пустоту скорее будут излишни.

Answer (score 2):

Для проверки наличия элементов в массиве есть функция empty(), а для подсчета количества элементов массива используйте функцию count()